# Move subfolder elsewhere and rename based on parent using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have many report folders under different parent folders that has the following structure:

```
C:\Users\USER\Downloads\LTFT01\Report
C:\Users\USER\Downloads\LTFT02\Report
C:\Users\USER\Downloads\LTFT03\Report
```

What I want to do is, if any of the report folders are **non-empty**, then move that report folder elsewhere and rename the folder with the original parent folder in the name. Such as LTFT01Report and LTFT02Report.

I have the 'test if it's non-empty' bit ready, but I have no idea what to do from here. I don't know really how *foreach* works so I haven't been able to implement that (even after searching!)

```
If (Test-Path -Path "C:\Users\USER\Downloads\*\Report\*"
```

Edit: It seems I need to clarify for some the following:

1. I'm new to coding, and new to PowerShell as of this week
2. I've googled a ton and found a bunch of answers, but nothing pertinent to my question (directly) or it's left me confused :(
3. I would really appreciate a nudge in the right direction rather than a git gud.
4. I *think* I need a foreach, hence my last line of the question, but not sure. Again - newbie here!

Comment: There is a wealth of information regarding this question online. Please do some testing and scripting yourself. Once you got some code, please replace your 'etc etc.' in order to show some effort.

Comment: Hey mate, thanks for your advice. I'm exceptionally new to PowerShell (as in I've just started over the last few days) and I'm also new to coding in general and I wouldn't even classify myself as a coder. So as for your suggestion, I have tried, but don't even know where to start. I've also searched, but nothing that seems to answer my question. Regardless, this aint dark souls mate. I put the etc etc since I didn't have anything there. @Alex_P

Comment: Jo mate, this might not be Dark Souls but coding can be difficult in the beginning and SO is not a coding service. Try the following commands: `Get-ChildItem` and `Move-Item`. Start with one file, etc etc.

Comment: @Alex_P Thanks for the suggestion! I'll try that out and update with my findings :)

Comment: It's OK to be new to anything. We've all been there and will continue to be because stuff changes/new stuff. This is why the PowerShell help files exist. The answer to what you are doing are examples in the help files. Also, as noted, tons of free training all over the web ([training sites](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/powershell/index.htm), blogs, articles) and [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=powershell+in+a+month+of+lunches+latest+edition), [books](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=powershell+beginning&ref=nb_sb_noss_2).

Comment: @postanote thanks for the advice. I've been able to come up with an answer below, that basically solved my problem. Though I did end up with another issue as a result, which I highlighted in my answer and made a new question to not clutter this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65054811/moving-same-name-folders-into-another-folder

Comment: Adil, good on you mate. There are always multiple ways to derive an answer. Some more elegant than the other. Yet, use what works, then come back and improve on it as your skills improve. Never try and do everything at once. Know what your end results if to be before you ever begin, break that into individual steps, research the individual steps, resolve the individual steps, ensuring you are getting what you'd expect at each step, then put it all together. Always start with the help files (explanations/examples). Save the frustration for the hard stuff. ;-}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP here!

So I've been able to create an answer based on some research:

```
#Get report folder path
$ReportPath = "C:\Users\USER\Downloads\*\Report"
$MasterReportPath = "C:\Users\USER\Downloads\MasterReports"

#Rename report folder to {currentparentname}report
Get-Item -Path $ReportPath | ForEach-Object {$a = $_.FullName | split-path -Parent | split-path -leaf; Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $a"Report"}

#Move report folder
$AnyNamedReportFolder = Get-Item "C:\Users\USER\Downloads\*\*Report*" -Exclude *.jmx, *.csv
Move-Item -Path $AnyNamedReportFolder -Destination $MasterReportPath
```

Definitely isn't elegant, but does the job. Since I have the main answer to this question, I'll mark it as answered. However there is an issue with this, which is that if this is run multiple times then same named folders will not move (since it doesn't append a unique number or character). I've highlighted this in a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65054811/moving-same-name-folders-into-another-folder), should you be interested. If all you need is a one time working script, then the above script worked for me.

[Moving Same Name Folders into Another Folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65054811/moving-same-name-folders-into-another-folder)

Comment: I've now also answered my secondary question, but for the sake of not cluttering this question, please refer to the link under my answer. Thanks!